# How to receive a timeout error from MessageBoxTimeout using iType = vbInformation in VB6?

Tags: vb6

Calling MessageBoxTimeout function from user32.dll is not returning timeout when using iType = vbInformation, it always returns vbOK, so I can not know when a timeout error occurs.

Code is following:

```
Public Function MsgBoxDelay(strMsg As String, strTitle As String, iTimeout As Long, iType As Integer) As Integer
    On Error GoTo _error
    
    MsgBoxDelay = MessageBoxTimeout(FrmFoo.hwnd, strMsg, strTitle, iType, 0, iTimeout * 1000)

    If MsgBoxDelay <> vbYes And MsgBoxDelay <> vbNo And MsgBoxDelay <> vbOK Then
        Call SaveLog("MsgBoxDelay: Timeout Error")
        gbAATimedOut = True
    End If

    Exit Function

_error:
    MsgBox "VB Error - Function MsgBoxDelay: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
         & "Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf _
         & "Description: " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"
End Function
```

Has anyone had this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've never used that API call, especially in VB6, but does your messagebox just have a single 'OK' button? If so, the warning in [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7914/MessageBoxTimeout-API) may apply: "Note that when a Message Box with only an OK button (MB_OK Flag) is used, the return value is always 1.".

Comment: Thansks for your comment, I solved (or jump) this using a Timer like function, this is not a good solution but results the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
Declare Auto Function MBoxTime Lib "user32.dll" Alias "MessageBoxTimeout" (
        ByVal hwnd As IntPtr,
        ByVal text As String,
        ByVal title As String,
        ByVal type As UInteger,
        ByVal wLanguageId As Int16,
        ByVal milliseconds As Int32) As Integer
```

---

```
test:
MBoxTime(New System.IntPtr(0), "Something went wrong!", "Process pic", 0, 0, 3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a work around setting a timer before MsgBoxTimeout and another after that call and it results *almost* the same.

Comment: It's a long time since I did any programming (I'm 75 now), but I'd probably have done the same.